# Bing maps textbox search

Tags: vb.net, xaml, bing-maps, bing, bing-api

Hi I"m trying to get my Bing map api to read a text box which will have a postcode or address in that it will locate. Currently after a lot of trial and error I have got it to search by coordinates coordinates which have been directly type into the tag option within the button on my Xaml. I was wondering if some one had an idea on how I would go about adding a textbox which the user can simple type the address into.

textbox (address) --> Button(Click) ----> Map searchs

Current Xaml Code

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="MainWindow"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid >
    <m:Map CredentialsProvider="MY KEY" x:Name="BingMap">
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" Margin="92,279,0,0" Click="ChangeMapView_Click" x:Name="BTN1" Tag="39.3683,-95.2734,0.0000 4.0000"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="111" Margin="212,277,0,0" x:Name="TXT1"/>
    </m:Map>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

VB Code

```
   Private Sub ChangeMapView_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
    ' Parse the information of the button's Tag property
    Dim tagInfo() As String = (CType(sender, Button)).Tag.ToString().Split(" "c)
    Dim center As Location = CType(locConverter.ConvertFrom(tagInfo(0)), Location)
    Dim zoom As Double = System.Convert.ToDouble(tagInfo(1))


    ' Set the map view
    BingMap.SetView(center, zoom)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the users query into the Bing Maps REST geocoding service to get it's coordinates. You can find documentation on how to do this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh757509.aspx